# Android app development with Clojure

Tags: android, emacs, clojure

I am absolutely new to lein-droid and am trying [this tutorial](https://github.com/alexander-yakushev/events/blob/master/tutorial.md).

I have followed the steps for setting up in the tutorial, now I have 2 problems:

1. After connecting my Android smartphone to my laptop and running `lein droid doall` in terminal, I do not see anything happening in my phone, also I do not see any nREPL being opened.
2. What is meant by entering "local machine" for Host after doing `M-x cider` in emacs? Should I enter the word "localmachine" or is this the name of my laptop or my smartphone? Couldn't I just run `M-x cider-jack-in` for this purpose?

@Mark Fischer Update of my problems (this is step by step what I have tried (i have a 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS os)):

1. downloaded android-sdk_r24.3.4-linux.tgz for linux from [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/sdk/index.html#Other), unpacked it and run the binary `android` file, installed `SDK version >=15 (Android 4.0.3 or higher)`, `Android Build Tools version >=20`,`Android Support Repository` from the manager.
2. Since I use CIDER on Emacs, I put

   ```
   :android-user {:dependencies [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.8.1"]]
        :android {:aot-exclude-ns ["cider.nrepl.middleware.util.java.parser"
                                     "cider.nrepl" "cider-nrepl.plugin"]}}


   {:user {:plugins [ [lein-droid "0.4.0-alpha4"] ] }}
   ```

   in my ~/.lein/profiles.clj as sugessted in the tutorials.
3. I create a new project with `lein new droid superapp my.company.superapp :activity MyActivity :target-sdk 15 :app-name SuperApp` (copy-paste from tutorial) and define the path to the android package (android-sdk-linux) i downloaded and unpacked from the android website in `project.clj`. I also change the `neko` version in `project.clj` :dependencies to `"4.0.0-alpha1"` as mentioned in the tutorials.
4. I connect my Huawei smartphone to the laptop, and in the terminal run (first from home directory) `lein droid doall`, i get this:

   ```
   'droid' is not a task. See 'lein help'.

   Did you mean this?
            do
   ```

   ,then i try it from within the supperapp directory, get this notifications:

   ```
   (Warning: profile :android-common not found.)
   (Warning: profile :android-user not found.)
   SDK platform 15 is not installed.
   Please install it from your Android SDK manager.
   ```

So the first problem occurs. I open the sdk manager and the `sdk-platform API 23, Rev 1` is marked as installed. How should I proceed by now?

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the [lein droid Tutorial](https://github.com/clojure-android/lein-droid/wiki/Tutorial)? There's a section on [connecting to the REPL](https://github.com/clojure-android/lein-droid/wiki/Tutorial#editors-and-ides) that describes the "local machine" better, it's just "localhost".

The command `lein droid doall` is creating a neko nrepl server that does the communication with your device. It creates a default port on your local dev machine (localhost) port 9999 by default, so you should tell Cider to connect to that.

There's some suggestion on that site to check if the 9999 port opened using netstat, and looking in the logcat logs for it being created, and more options on debugging the problem.

Comment: I have read the tutorial. I do `M-x cider-connect`, localhost is found by default as Host, and i enter 9999 for Port. I get this error: `nREPL: Direct connection failed`.

Comment: did you look at logcat and netstat results as per the lein-droid tutorial pages (not the events tutorial you linked, they are 2 different tutorials)? is the port open on your machine? are you using windows/mac or linux?

Comment: I am quite new to the whole thema, so i went through the troubleshooting part. When i run `<sdk-path>/platform-tools/adb logcat` or `adb logcat -s neko.tools.repl` in the terminal i get: `* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
- waiting for device -` and then i waits for minutes and nothing happens. I have Ubuntu 14.04 (linux).

Comment: I also get a long list of stuff at the terminal after creating the events project and running `lein droid doall`

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and add specific details of your problem, particularly around running netstat, and grepping in your logcat for nREPL, then I can update my answer, the comments thread isn't the place to fix this.

Comment: okey, i will report a step-by-step of my trying, and let you know where the problems occure. thanks for your help